# How would I use a function with two variables python?

Tags: python, function, sum

I'm supposed to calculate an approximation for the absolute value of any integer x. I need to write a function `abs_approx(x, N)` that calculates the N first terms of the sum and returns f(x). I am to use the function to compute the approximation for N=1,2,3,4.
The function is:

[image: function]

This is my following program, but I get that the absolute value of 1 is 0.3009465364104349. Which is completely wrong. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
from math import pi, cos

def abs_approx(x,N):
    
    N=4
    sum=0
    for n in range(0,N+1):
        num=cos((2*n-1)*x)
        denom=(2*n-1)**2
        sum+=num/denom
     
    f=pi/2-4/pi*(sum)    
    
    return f

print(abs_approx(1,1))
```

print: 0.3009465364104349

Comment: btw why do you overwrite parameter `N` inside the function? You have `N=4`.

Comment: You are looping from 0 instead of 1 - I haven't yet checked if this is the whole problem.

Comment: Just checked - looks like it is the whole problem. Though you should also choose a variable name other than `sum`, which overrides a builtin.

Comment: Going to vote to close as "caused by typo".

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to loop from `1` to `N`?

```py
from math import pi, cos

def abs_approx(x, N):
    
    sigma = 0
    for n in range(1, N + 1):
        num = cos((2*n-1)*x)
        denom = (2*n-1)**2
        sigma += num/denom
     
    f = (pi/2) - (4/pi*(sigma))
    
    return f

print(abs_approx(1, 4))
```

Output:

```
0.988880798353344
```